# Ordem de execução de migrations

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá!

Em meu primeiro emprego, trabalhei utilizando code-first com o Entity Framework 4. Neste tempo, constatei uma limitação nele: as migrations geradas somente rodavam em ordem. Por exemplo, se em minha branch duas pessoas estiverem trabalhando com persistência, pode acontecer de migrations geradas não serem executadas. Isso dava-se por conta de uma migration com timestamp menor a última registrada no banco não ser executada.

Um pouco depois, saí da empresa e a partir daí trabalhei apenas com NHibernate e migrations utilizando o MigSharp. Porém, por questão de organização e praticidade sempre preferi o Entity e estive pensando na possibilidade de implementá-lo em novos projetos da empresa. A questão dessa obrigatoriedade de rodar as migrations em ordem não daria certo aqui: Se a branch master sofrer uma correção de persistência de última hora para resolver problemas já em produção, a branch de desenvolvimento teria que alterar todo o timestamp das migrations já criadas e que ainda não estão na master, ou então as migrations não seriam executadas.

Como comentei, tive esse problema no Entity Framework 4. Minha pergunta é: Nas novas versões do Entity Framework existe alguma configuração que permite a execução das migrations sem uma ordem obrigatória? Caso não tenha, qual o modo mais 'profissional' de evitar que problemas como esse ocorram durante o desenvolvimento de tarefas junto a correções de última hora, ou até mesmo a processos de integração contínua ao realizar um push?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nas novas versões do Entity Framework existe alguma configuração que permite a execução das migrations sem uma ordem obrigatória?

Sim, o mecanismo de migrações automáticas. Neste caso, o dispositivo de migração confere se há alguma alteração pendente e a executa em automático. Não é nem preciso gerar novas migrações.

Este mecanismo é recomendado usar quando o projeto está no início e essas colisões são comuns. A partir do momento que o sistema está pronto para ir em produção, o recomendado é voltar para migrações manuais.

> Caso não tenha, qual o modo mais 'profissional' de evitar que problemas como esse ocorram durante o desenvolvimento de tarefas junto a correções de última hora, ou até mesmo a processos de integração contínua ao realizar um push?

Excluir todas as migrações com colisão e gerar uma nova. Vamos supor 3 migrações quaisquer, sendo que a penúltima conflita em alguma coisa com a última:

```
201603152143014_Migration1.cs
201603161530010_Migration2.cs
201603182010501_Migration3.cs
```

Precisamos reverter para `Migration1` e excluir as outras duas. Usamos, portanto:

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:201603152143014_Migration1
```

Depois usamos os comandos rotineiros:

```
PM> Add-Migration Migrations2e3
PM> Update-Database
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Cigano. Mais uma dúvida: Caso as migrations já estejam em produção, a reversão de migration poderia ocasionar na perda de dados. E a branch que já está em produção, onde também ocorrem correções emergenciais, tem migrations já executadas em produção e com timestamp superior do que as migrations não executadas em produção da branch de desenvolvimento. Isso já aconteceu porque o bug era tão crítico que não poderia esperar o desenvolvimento de novas funcionalidades acabar para subir a correção. Neste caso, como executar as migrations de dev em prod?

Comment: Você só poderia reverter *migrations* que ainda não foram executadas em produção. Se caso alguma *migration* foi feita indevidamente executada, você terá que criar mais outra *migration* para reverter essa *migration* que foi errada.